# Animating an image view inside a collectionview cell after it becomes visible

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `collectionview` with fullscreen `cells` and it automatically scrolls one by one. I want to add an animation to an `imageView` inside my cells. But i want animation to start after automatic scrolling finishes. I tried the code below but it works only for the first cell.

I call the animation function in this line `cell.alpImage.getBiggerAnim()`. But as i have said before, it works only for the first cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AlphabetCollectionViewCell

    if (indexPath.item >= alpImageArray.count - 1) {
        cell.alpImage.isHidden = true
        cell.startAgain.isHidden = false
        cell.readyLabel.isHidden = true
        cell.startAgain.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startAgainPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    } else if (indexPath.item == 0) {
        cell.readyLabel.isHidden = false
        cell.alpImage.isHidden = true
    } else {
        cell.startAgain.isHidden = true
        cell.readyLabel.isHidden = true
        cell.alpImage.isHidden = false
        cell.alpImage.image = UIImage(named: alpImageArray[indexPath.row] + ".png")
    }
    cell.alpImage.getBiggerAnim()
    return cell
}
```

These are the functions that manages automatic scrolling:

```
func scrollToNextCell(){
    let cellSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
    let contentOffset = myCollectionView.contentOffset
    width: cellSize.width, height: cellSize.height), animated: true)
    alphabetSoundPlay()
}
var myTimer: Timer?
func startTimer() {
    myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0,
                                   target: self,
                                   selector: #selector(scrollToNextCell),
                                   userInfo: nil,
                                   repeats: true)
}
```

This is my animation extension:

```
extension UIView {
    func getBiggerAnim() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6 , animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.6, y: 0.6)
        },completion: { finish in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6){
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't call animation method in `cellForItem`, it gets called way before scrolling is finished. What you can do is calling it in UIScrollViewDelegate's `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` callback. You need to find out which cell is visible though.

Comment: tried calling `getBiggerAnim` on main thread?

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this..

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   for cell: UICollectionViewCell in self.myCollectionView.visibleCells {
    var indexPath = self.myCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell)!
    let acell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AlphabetCollectionViewCell

    print("\(indexPath)")
    acell.alpImage.getBiggerAnim()
   }
}
```

Comment: I think we should more focus on solution not the language only. But yet I have converted my answer in Swift.. Thanks.!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When i try this i get an error in this line. `cell.alpImage.getBiggerAnim()` It does not let me to access `alpImage` I have tried replacing UICollectionViewCell with AlphabetCollectionViewCell but it did not work either

Comment: Didn' work. Also indexPath gets printed in the console only if i scroll to the next cell. When it scrolls automatically it does not get printed.

Comment: Okay..! This is because you are setting offset of scrollview. You will need to add a completion block when you are setting offset to show the next cell and then in the completion block call 'getBiggerAnim' .